# Smoothly joining two rectangles using Python

Tags: python, coordinates

I am looking for the Math and steps involved not using a tool. We have PostGIS but its an old version so we are working with the data in Python.

Given three coordinates:

- -107.37, 52.46
- -103.24, 52.62
- -101.09, 53.97

I then join them to form a line.

I then build buffered polygons around each line segment (20NM) - resulting in two rectangles. If there was another coordinate I would have 3 rectangles and so on.

This is what the output looks like when the rectangles are assembled:

[image: Joined rectangles]

However, what I really want is to have that triangular gap - sealed up with a curve.

Like this (did it by hand):

[image: with curve]

So I have everything working but I have no idea how to properly join these rectangles so that they have a nicely fitted curve to fill in that triangular gap.

Since I am assembling the polygon data myself I can easily identify the points that need to be connected.

Is there a way to join two points with a curve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this is the most elegant approach, but it worked for me and maybe it will help somebody get started in the right direction. If you have 1.5+ of PostgreSQL then use ST_Buffer with different endcaps - I am sure it performs this in a much more efficient manner).

Because I have the two rectangles and all their coordinates, the biggest problem was insuring that I am joining the exposed open parts and not touching the other side (which side is the kink on?)

[image: graphic]

**How do I know which points to join?**

I've built a "Rectangle" class that has the points TL, TR, BL, BR. They are always oriented along the line.

That way I always know that a TL will link to a BL and a TR will link to a BR.

**How do I know whether to join BL to TL or BR to TR?**

Based on the difference in angle between the two rectangles I can determine what side has the kink.

In my Rectangle class I am also keeping track of the angle and normalizing it to 0->360 degrees. I don't think this was the best approach but it made it easier for me to understand the problem in my head. I had to do some basic math when the difference in angle was greater then 180 degrees as it causes the kink to flip to the other side.

**How do I build the curve?**

Once I have identified which points I wish to join (j1 from rectangle 1, j2 from rectangle 2), I need to find a third point somewhere out in the middle (see example above (pa1)). This is used for quadratic bezier curves which I use to build the arc between the points. This third point is used to "pull" the curve away from the rectangles.

The python function I used to build the curves is:

```
def get_bezier_curve(j1, j2, pa1, segments=8):
    """
    Given 2 points (j1, and j2) calculate the bezier curve
    between them - using point pa1 to pull  the curve away
    from the points.

    Segments determines the number of points calculated for
    the curve.
    """
    # j1 is always first item
    coords = [j1]

    step = 1.0 / segments

    # Quadratic bezier curve
    for t in drange(step, 1.0-step, step):
        x = ((1-t)*(1-t)*j1[0] + 2*(1-t)*t*pa1[0]+t*t*j2[0])
        y = ((1-t)*(1-t)*j1[1] + 2*(1-t)*t*pa1[1]+t*t*j2[1])
        coords.append((x,y))

    # j2 is always last item
    coords.append(j2)
    return coords
```

To find this, I find the intersection between the inner lines (lines on the side of a rectangle that doesnt have a kink) (i1). Then I create a vector from this towards the original point (p1) that both rectangles share (the original point before buffering). I then increase the length of this to find my point to pull the curve (pa1).

I then build the curve using the above algorithm between j1, and j2 using pa1 pull out the curve.

I then create a polygon out of i1 -> j1 ... bezier curve points ... j2 -> i1.

I then take all the kink polygons, and the rectangle polygons I have and perform a cascaded union (using GEOS from GeoDjango - although you could use Shaply) to collapse these polygons into a single polygon.

Note: To reasons I do not quite fully understand when taking a MultiPolygon of all this data and performing a cascaded union I am not always given a Polygon. Sometimes I am given a GeometryCollection of a useless LineString (no idea where this is coming from) and the combined Polygon. I am guessing this is some side-effect to collapsing certain geometries and stuff not fitting correctly - maybe rounding errors - not sure.